# How can I write dates to ISO 8601 format using JSON Writes?

Tags: json, scala, date, playframework, iso8601

I've got a case calss

```
import java.sql.Date
case class GetMilestoneLanguage(
                               ...
                   due_date: Option[Date],
                                ...
                   )
object GetMilestoneLanguage {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[GetMilestoneLanguage]
}
```

Its outputting the JSON in UTC - and I need it to be iso 8601. I'm NOT use Joda time.

What the easiest way to achieve getting the date in iso 8601?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Writes}
import play.api.libs.json.Writes.dateWrites // do not import everything here, especially DefaultDateWrites

case class GetMilestoneLanguage(param1: String, dueDate: Option[java.sql.Date])

object GetMilestoneLanguage {
  implicit val customDateWrites: Writes[java.util.Date] = dateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

  implicit val writes =  Json.writes[GetMilestoneLanguage]
}
```

The key here is to define your own implicit `Writes[java.util.Date]`. If you import `DefaultDateWrites` your `customDateWrites` will be silently ignored (I wonder why there is no ambiguous implicit warning).

Comment: You could do `import play.api.libs.json.Writes.{ dateWrites => _, _ => _ }` to import everything but `dateWrites`, I think.  Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't know that syntax.

Comment: Thanks - just going to scootch my accept over here - as it does save the boiler plate by using json write macro helper

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `Writes[java.util.Date]` using the helper provided on the `Writes` companion object.  You won't be able to use the `Json.writes` macro helper though.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._

case class GetMilestoneLanguage(param1: String, dueDate: Option[Date], param3: String)

object GetMilestoneLanguage {
  implicit val writes = (
    (__ \ "param1").write[String] and
    (__ \ "due_date").write(dateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")) and
    (__ \ "param3").write[String]
  )(unlift(GetMilestoneLanguage.unapply))
}
```